# Hacer que mi web ocupe toda la pantalla

Tags: html5, bootstrap, google-apps-script

Estoy construyendo una web con Google Apps Script y quiero que ocupe toda la pantalla del dispositivo y que el contenido no la rebase, es decir, la web se debe ver completamente en la pantalla sin necesidad de ir desplazandose abajo o arriba para ver parte del contenido.

Mi primer problema consiste en que quiero colocar un texto al final de la pantalla pero me lo coloca al final del contenido de la hoja.
Vean el ejemplo:
HTML

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include('CSS'); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content" class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row align-items-end">                             <!-------------------------------------------------- Peu-->
        <div class="col-12">
          <p class="fs-4 text-center">El·laborant per: Andreu i Joan Carles.</p>
        </div>
      </div>                                                         <!-------------------------------------------------- Peu-->
    </div>
    <?!= include('JSClient'); ?>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" 
      integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```css
 body,html,#content,#liniaPantalla {  
   margin:0px;  
   min-height: 100vh; 
   width:100%;
 }
```

Resultado

[image: Quiero que esta linea de texto aparexca al pie de la web]

Estoy utilizando bootstrap y no he encontrado la manera de conseguir lo que quiero. Solo se me ocurre tener un div con una altura que varie en funcion del contenido de la web para que ocupe el resto de la altura, de manera que la linea este siempre al pié. Pero tampoco se como conseguirlo.

Por otra parte tengo el problema que si meto un contenido largo, como un listado, aunque aplique la clase "overflow-auto", la web crece más allá del limite de la pantalla.

Comment: He publicado una respuesta. Si requieres mayor orientación por favor [edit] y agrega un [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Bastaria usar `height: 100vh` para los contenidos para que ocupe la altura completa (al inicio).

Luego para no hacer scroll, se agrega `overflow: hidden` al **HTML**

Pero sea lo sea que esas agregando, debes agregar al body o al contenedor `content`.

El resto del codigo que agregue es para el demo. El fondo rojo es del `content`.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box
}

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}

body {
    min-height: 100vh
}

#content, #liniaPantalla {  
    margin: 0px;  
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh; 
} 

.container-fluid {
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3)
}

p {
    margin: 0
}
```

```html
<div id="content" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row align-items-end">                             <!-------------------------------------------------- Peu-->
          <div class="col-12">
            <p class="fs-4 text-center">El·laborant per: Andreu i Joan Carles.</p>
          </div>
        </div>                                                         <!-------------------------------------------------- Peu-->
      </div>
      <?!= include('JSClient'); ?>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" 
        integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous">
      </script>
```

Comment: Gracias Narciso por tu tiempo. 
Tal vez no me explique bien en mi pregunta.  Una de las cosas que necesito es que el literal "El·laborat per: Andreu i Joan Carles." al que le he dado la clase de bootstrap "align-items-end" se coloque al final de la página en la parte inferior de la pantalla, independientemente del contenido de la web.

Answer (score 0):

Las aplicaciones web creadas con Google Apps Script tienen limitaciones. Por ejemplo, hay limitaciones para las `<meta>` y esta se deben indicar del lado del servidor

```
function doGet(e){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
     .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
}
```

Referencia

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web